# Simple way to style an Google Maps Infowindow without using Infobox

Tags: css, google-maps

Is there a simple way of styling an Infowindow without using Infobox? I just need to reduce its margins/padding.

Thanks,

[ simon.cpu ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, set the margin of your content. In chrome developer console you can inspect the div and set the margin as needed and mark it as important. Like so,

```
    <div id="INFOWINDOW" style="margin-bottom:-1% !important;">Info Window Content</div>
```

If you want to reduce the margin from all sides the simply replace **margin-bottom** with **margin** with will reduce the margin from all sides by the value you have set.

Hope this helps.